# No Symfony tab after upgrading to PHPStorm 9

Tags: phpstorm

After upgrading to `PHPStorm9` and installing all plugins (including whole bunch of `Symfony2` plugins) I still really miss `Symfony` tab, placed next to `Project` and `Structure` tabs on the left edge of the screen. Was this deleted or is there any chance to get this tab back?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any screenshots of such tab by any chance? If that was  [Framework MVC Structure Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7143?pr=phpStorm) .. then it is no longer supported.

Comment: @LazyOne I updated the question with a screenshot from PHPStorm 8.

Comment: AFAIK it should be provided by Symfony2 plugin. Unfortunately I do not use that plugin so cannot really help. I may only suggest to: 1) check if that window is listed in `View | Tool Windows` 2) Make sure that Symfony2 plugin settings are setup correctly in Settings/Preferences (e.g. that support is enabled for this project)

Comment: @LazyOne unfortunately there's no `Symfony2` option in menu you pointed. All plugins are correctly set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed this tab; use "Navigate -> Symfony Symbol" instead

Comment: Why removing? It was really usable!